# What warning to enable that implicit conversion from typedef (uint32_t) to uint32_t results in warning, clang

Tags: c, clang, warnings, typedef

I'd like the given example to result in a compiler warning because there is an implicit conversion from error_t to int.

I am using the segger clang compiler for ARM with C, not C++.

```
typedef uint32_t error_t ; 

error_t Test(error_t test){
  return test;
}

int main(){
  error_t e = 0;
  uint32_t t32 = Test(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `typedef` is just an alias for a type, so an `error_t` is the same as a `uint32_t`.  As such, there will be no warning for the conversion.

Warnings for type conversions between arithmetic types would only occur if there is a possible loss of precision, and then only with certain options enabled not included in `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.